# Extract unique items in a column and map with all items in another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `df` which looks like this:

```
Col1    Col2    Label
0   D1  C38 1
1   D1  C65 1
2   D1  C53 1
3   D2  C02 1
4   D2  C01 1
5   D4  C73 1
```

I want to first extract all the unqiue items from `Col1` and each unique item in `Col1` needs to be mapped to all items in `Col2` except for those corresponding items that are already having a connection with label as 1 in third column.

For example, if we take `D1` in `Col1` it is having three repetitions with label as 1 in third column `Label`. Now, map `D1` with remaining items in col2 i.e., `C02 C01 C73 C61 C03` and add these new connections in the same `Col1` and `Col2` with label as 0.

The output of dataframe needs to be like this:

```
Col1    Col2    Label
0   D1  C38 1
1   D1  C65 1
2   D1  C53 1
3   D1  C02 0
4   D1  C01 0
5   D1  C73 0

6   D2  C02 1
7   D2  C01 1
8   D2  C38 0
9   D2  C65 0
10  D2  C53 0
11  D2  C73 0

12  D4  C73 1
13  D4  C02 0
14  D4  C01 0
15  D4  C38 0
16  D4  C65 0
17  D4  C53 0
```

Is there a way to do this? Appreciate your suggestions

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Really helpful! Yes, you are right, the order is important. I would like to see the 1s first and 0s next in each case

Comment: Create the combination as in the dup link, then `sort_values` with appropriate order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option to keep the order:

```
cols = ['Col1', 'Col2']
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df[c].unique() for c in cols], names=cols)

out = (df
 .set_index(cols).reindex(idx, fill_value=0).reset_index()
 .sort_values(by=['Col1', 'Label'], ascending=[True, False],
              kind='stable', ignore_index=True)  
)
```

Or, if the groups cannot be sorted:

```
cols = ['Col1', 'Col2']
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df[c].unique() for c in cols], names=cols)

out = (df
 .set_index(cols).reindex(idx, fill_value=0).reset_index()
 .groupby('Col1', group_keys=False)
 .apply(lambda g: g.sort_values(by='Label', ascending=False, kind='stable'))
 .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

output:

```
   Col1 Col2  Label
0    D1  C38      1
1    D1  C65      1
2    D1  C53      1
3    D1  C02      0
4    D1  C01      0
5    D1  C73      0
6    D2  C02      1
7    D2  C01      1
8    D2  C38      0
9    D2  C65      0
10   D2  C53      0
11   D2  C73      0
12   D4  C73      1
13   D4  C38      0
14   D4  C65      0
15   D4  C53      0
16   D4  C02      0
17   D4  C01      0
```